# Hide a specific product in Woocommerce product widget

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, widget, product

In WooCommerce, I am trying hide a specific product in the Woocommerce product widget.

I found a solution to exclude it via category:

```
function exclude_widget_categories($args){
    $exclude = "11,10,8,7,9"; // IDs of excluded product categories
    $args["exclude"] = $exclude;
    return $args;
}
add_filter("widget_categories_args","exclude_widget_categories");
```

**But thats not what I want**. I need it for a **specific product** with the **id 2386**.

How to hide a specific product in woocommerce product widget?

Answer (score 0):

You can use widget_post_args filter.

```
add_filter('widget_posts_args', function(){
$params['post__not_in'] = array(2386);
   return $params;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a custom function hooked in **`woocommerce_products_widget_query_args`** filter hook this way:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_products_widget_query_args', 'exclude_product_from_widget', 10, 1 );
function exclude_product_from_widget( $query_args ){
    // HERE define your product IDs to exclude in the array
    $product_ids = array(2386);

    $query_args['post__not_in'] = $product_ids;
    return $query_args;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.

Tested and works